# Eclipse Folder is transparent/grayed out. What does it mean?

Tags: eclipse, java-native-interface

My jni folder in Eclipse looks like this:

[image]

It is grayed out and has a diagonal line across it.  What does it mean?  I can still edit my native C++ code in this folder and see the changes as I test the application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means the directory is being filtered from the source locations. It seems you can use this to exclude files that are not source from a source folder, although I've never used it.

I got rid of this irritation in Eclipse Indigo CDT by:

**(Project) Properties ->C/C++ General ->Paths and Symbols ->Source Location Tab ->Edit Filter... ->Remove**

Answer (score 2):

You probably have something in the folder that is deprecated.

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm

Comment: The code is C++ and not related to Java but +1 for link!  It gives the same icon and transparency on all sub folders within the jni folder as well.