# What is a "deleted" folder in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, ide

In my eclipse there is a folder with the name `HttpsServer` which looks like the following picture:

[image]

What is this folder? How can I create such folder in eclipse?

Comment: Have a look to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342317/eclipse-folder-is-transparent-grayed-out-what-does-it-mean

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse Folder is transparent/grayed out. What does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342317/eclipse-folder-is-transparent-grayed-out-what-does-it-mean)